# Mixing alignment on a single line in Flex TLF

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, tlf

I want to mix alignments in a single line in flex using TLF.

Ie., on each given line, I'd like something like this:

```
the quick brown fox|1
     jumps over the|2
           lazy dog|3
```

In essence there's simply 2 columns there - the left column is right aligned, and the right column is left aligned.

The docs on this are pretty scarce, and I'm not sure where to start.  Anyone have any ideas?